# Isometry in Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The question is to show that an isometry from $\mathbb{E}^{1} \to \mathbb{E}^{1}$ is of the form $x \to ax + b $ from first principles, and determine the values $a$ can take. From my notes I know for Euclidian $n$ space an isometry $\mathbb{E}^{n} \to \mathbb{E}^{n}$ is of the form $x \to Ax + b$ where $A$ is an n x n orthogonal matrix and $b$ a column vector. So I guess for this question $a$ is equal to 1 or -1, but the proofs  in my notes are very informal so I am unsure on doing this by first principles.

Comment: What's the definition of isometry?  If a map isn't of the above form, can you show it violates this definition?

Comment: Isometries are distance preserving. I think I can easily show that if we have a map of the form ax + b with a equal to 1 or -1 then it is isometry, but am not sure how to show the reverse direction.

Comment: First characterize isometries $f$ that fix $0$; particularly, what possibilities are there for $f(1)$, and how much freedom is left after such a choice is made?

Comment: Okay, so is it something like that for $f$ to fix $0$ we require $f = ax$ with $a$ some real number. Now we need $1 = |f(0) - f(1)|$ hence $a = 1$ or $a = -1$. Now translating by any real number $b$ will not effect any distances and we are done?

Comment: Not exactly: _assuming_ $f(x) = ax$ is far too much. But if $f(0) = 0$, then $$|f(1)| = |f(1) - f(0)| = |1 - 0| = 1.$$That all but determines $f(1)$. Now let $x$ be an arbitrary real number, and use the facts that $|f(x)| = |x|$ and $|f(x) - f(1)| = |x - 1|$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to characterize all $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that, for any $x,y \in \mathbb R$, the distance between $x$ and $y$ equals the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$. In other words $|x - y| = |f(x) - f(y)|$

Let's suppose that $f(0) = b$. Letting $y=0$, we find

\begin{align}
  |x - 0| &= |f(x) - b|\\
  |x| &= |f(x) - b|\\
  f(x) - b &= \pm x\\
  f(x) &= \pm x + b
\end{align}